# Wordpress short code to display in template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wunderground

I would like to hardcode this WordPress short code in my template file. Is there a way to do it?

```
[wunderground location="Philadelphia, PA" numdays="3" layout="simple"]
```

Currently only works if i add into Page WTSIWYG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode